# TexShop preview document-surround colour

Tags: texshop, preview

I would like to change the colour of the TexShop preview window background *surrounding* a preview document, rather than *behind document pages* (see note).

I would like to change it from the default grey to black, so that when I preview a document with a colour or white background, it is displayed more vividly, so to speak.

I cannot see how to achieve this via the themes settings in TexShop; can anyone assist?

> Note: TeXShop preview has a background option in the theme which is readily changed, however, this change effects the colour of the background of *document pages* — i.e. shows through from *behind* document pages: instead of showing up white, pages take on the colour option etc. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I see no way to do this. However! I notice that in Dark Mode (which I use all the time) The background is (pretty close to?) black.

Comment: That's curious… none of my themes change the doc *surround* background… even as the *editor* background and text changes according to the theme… nothing changes in *preview* …

Comment: In Preview.app there is a setting for Window background color uder the General tab of its Preferences. I wonder if this changes it for all apps using PDFKit  for PDF display, like TeXShop. It's (almost?) black in my setup.

Comment: good suggestion, Herb, thanks for thinking this through with me; I've tested it on my setup and 'no dice', sadly! I'll continue looking…

Answer (score 2):

Go to TeXShop >> Preferences >> Themes and in the table, click on the box in Row `Preview` and Column `Background`. It'll open a color wheel, move the lightness slider all the way left for 100% brightness white.